# Emitting data from a child component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a child component, when data changes on this component I emit the data, I do this like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="john" v-model="users" @click="updateUsers">
```

When the user clicks on the checkbox, it runs the updateUsers method, which emits the this.users value.

```
updateUsers() {      
    this.$emit('users', this.users)
},
```

The issue is that the @click method runs before the v-model users updates. So nothing is emitted.

Am I approaching this in the wrong way? Basically I want it so that when the data changes on the child component, the parent is made aware of it and is passed the data.

Comment: I think you want to be using `change` instead so you can catch the instance of the value being updated then send the emit.

Comment: I agree with @lix it's better to use `change` instead of click.

Comment: Thanks @change worked!

Comment: Better still to watch the variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to be using `@change` instead so you can catch the instance of the value being updated then send the emit.

Answer (score 0):

When you want an updated variable to be emitted, [`watch`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property) the variable. Only look at the DOM when there's no viewmodel state to tell you what you need to know.

By using a `change` event to emit a data item, you're mingling concepts and depending on order of execution. The change event does not *guarantee* that the data item is updated by the time the handler fires. If you are going to emit from an event, you should emit `event.target.value`, not the data item which is updated separately.

If you want to emit the data item, you should be watching it for changes.

Since you're emitting changes, your component likely shouldn't own the data item, it should receive it as a prop.

Comment: Why would you use watch instead of change?

Comment: I would just like to say this method of using `watch` is more expensive than tracking DOM changes.

Comment: Because Vue is supposed to be model-centric, and you're actually interested in the data changing, not the DOM element.

Comment: @lix I'm not at all sure that's true, but even if it is, you're talking about a micro-optimization, which is a poor way to approach programming.  The change we are interested in happens in the data.

Comment: True you may not be concerned about the DOM element, but event driven updates are part of the model-centric approach and with a varitey of different events you may not want to update your model to encompass these changes. In my opinion this is just another method not a better approach.

Comment: You're tracking the change in two places. If you want to use an event, the event should emit `event.target.value`, not the data item.

Comment: The real difference is by using `watch` I'm assigning a watcher that won't leave memory until the component life cycle ends, by using the DOM event it'll leave memory after because of the flushing.

Comment: The real difference is that you're making a muddle of your code.